# How to run procedure from another unit?

Tags: delphi, scope, procedures, delphi-units

Well this kind of n00b question but I still can't figure it out. I have unit `main` with  procedure `Discard()` in it. Now I have another unit `engine` and I want to run from it procedure `Discard()` of unit `main`. I have main in `uses` section of `engine.pas`. I tried to call procedure with `main.Discard()` but no good. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to put the procedure's signature in your interface, like so:

```
unit main;

interface

procedure Discard();

implementation

procedure Discard();
begin
//do whatever
end;
```

Other units can only "see" whatever's listed in the interface section.

Answer (score 9):

In unit "Main" you declare Discard in the "interface" section:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses ...

procedure Discard (...); // only the declaration, not the entire procedure

implementation

... // code
```

Now in unit "Engine" you add "Main" to the "uses" section.

```
uses Main, ...
```

Thats it, you can call `Discard(...)` now. If there are more than one `Discard()` you can explicitely call *this* `Discard()` by using `Main.Discard()`.